# filtering and adding the object to array without duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Im trying to make sure I dont have this object in the array before adding it. If it is inside I want to remove it and add the new one at the top (very similar to a browser history)

```
    let numberArray =  [ {
  "name": "Smith",
    "number": "088-002-0002",
},
 {
  "name": "Jhon",
    "number": "088-111-2222",
},];

let test = { "name": "Smith",
  "number": "088-002-0002",};

numberArray.filter(obj => obj.number !== test.number);
numberArray.unshift(test);

console.log(numberArray);

//Expected
 Array [
 Object {
    "name": "Smith",
    "number": "088-002-0002",
 },
 Object {
   "name": "Jhon",
   "number": "088-111-2222",
 },
]
```

Comment: Are you going to use this operation a lot or very few times?

Comment: @molamk yes 10-15 max

Comment: The answers below are perfect for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `findIndex` and then check if the `indexOf > -1`, in that case, remove that index, and finally `unshift` the new object.

```js
// This is to illustrate -> "name": "Smithhhhh"
let numberArray = [{    "name": "Smithhhhh",    "number": "088-002-0002",  },  {    "name": "Jhon",    "number": "088-111-2222",  }],
    test = {  "name": "Smith",  "number": "088-002-0002",},
    indexOf = numberArray.findIndex(obj => obj.number === test.number);
    
if (indexOf !== -1) numberArray.splice(indexOf, 1);

numberArray.unshift(test);
console.log(numberArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes` and `indexOf` with `unshift` like so:

```
function addToArray(obj, arr) {
    if (arr.includes(obj)) {
        arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj), 1);
        arr.unshift(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` and `includes`?, this is comparing different references in memory.

Comment: @Ele what do you mean?

Comment: `let obj1 = {name: "Ele"}; let obj2 = {name: "Ele"}` `->` `obj1 === obj2 // returns false`

Comment: The function `includes` compares each object vs the object you're passing as param.  So, is comparing references in memory and not the keys, values within it.

Comment: How should I do it then?

Comment: `let index; if ((index = arr.findIndex(({number}) => obj.number === number)) > -1) {
        arr.splice(index, 1);
        arr.unshift(obj);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Search for the object using `.find()`. If an object is not returned, use `.unshift()` to update the array.

```js
let numberArray = [{
    "name": "Smith",
    "number": "088-002-0002",
  },
  {
    "name": "Jhon",
    "number": "088-111-2222",
  },
];

let test = {
  "name": "Smith",
  "number": "088-002-0002",
};



if (!numberArray.find(o => o.number === test.number)) {
  numberArray.unshift(test);
}



console.log(numberArray);
```